# How to identify the exact ajax call failure reason?

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, self-signed

I have a local web service running at one of my machines within the local network which is https with a self-signed certificate. As it is self-signed, Chrome (and other browsers) rejects the call from my javascript. I get an exception (goes to fail case) but with text as null and state as zero. It is the same state and text when it fails due to a DNS resolution issue (host not reachable) or similar errors. Is there any way to identify the exact error? I would like to identify the self-signed certificate issue so that I can request the user to trust the certificate manually.

**Note**: My website is HTTPS with proper certificate, however, the local service that I want to consume is https with a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
       async: 'false',
        type: 'GET',
         url: 'http://',
     success: function(data, textStatus ){
         console.log('STATUS: '+textStatus);
     },
     error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       console.log('STATUS: '+textStatus+'\nERROR THROWN: '+errorThrown);
     }
});
```

- **`async:false`** Makes your AJAX call synchronous making it being executed line by line, thus anything after the AJAX call will have to wait until it's completed.

> **Warning:** Synchronous AJAX call is deprecated because it may harm the user experience (by making it wait a lot).